# с++ вычислить значение выражения

Tags: c++

Найти значение выражения.
Пример входных данных: 2.4 -4.2 0.6 Пример выходных данных 4,726

По-ходу делаю что-то не то. Понятия не имею, как считать сигму.
Прошу помощи, как должно быть верно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double a,b,x,p,sum=0,n;
  cin >> a >> b >> x;
  n=10*x;
  for (int i=n;i<(-10*b);i++)
  {
    sum+=(pow((-1),(n+1))*pow(n,1.0/2.0))/(n*(n+2));
  }
  p=b/2*x;
  p=cos(p)/sin(p);
  p=pow(p,3)*sum;
  p=p+pow((abs(1-x*exp(x-b))),1.0/3.0);
  cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сигма считается через цикл, и в вашем коде он вроде даже есть. Поясните, чем вас не устраивает имеющийся код (я проголосовал за переоткрытие вопроса, но без пояснений он рискует вновь оказаться закрытым)

Comment: У вас тут "a" нет зачем вы его просите ввести ?

Comment: @andreymal В моём коде значение получается 4.219, а должно быть 4.726, при вводе значений из примера.

Comment: Я переписал пример . У меня получились другие значения. У вас не суммирует цикл for. В коде который вы привели в вопросе

Comment: И x не может быть у вас между -1<x<1 . Так как получается деление на ноль где b/2*x

Comment: Уранение имеет решение если b<0,  x !=0 , 10*x < -10*b , 10*x>0 и -10* b>0

Comment: Я переписал уравнение чтоб вводились корректные b и х. В ответе смотрите код, не знаю откуда вы взяли значения 4.726. У меня получается другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уравнение имеет решение, если b<0, x !=0 , 10*x < -10*b , 10*x>0 и -10* b>0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <QDebug>
using namespace std;
double b,x;
void cinB() {
    cin >> b;
    if (b>=0) {
       cout <<"Input b<0";
       cin >> b ;
    }

}

void cinX() {
    cin>>x;
    if (x<=0) {
        cout <<"Input x>0";
        cin >> x ;
    }
}
void cinXB () {
    if (10*x>=-10*b) {
        cout <<"It should be: 10*x<-10*b";
        cinB();
        cinX();
        cinXB();
    }
}

int main()
{
  double P,sum=0;
  cinB();
  cinX();
  cinXB();

  if (10*x<-10*b) {
      for (double n=10*x;n<(-10*b);n=n+1)
      {         
         sum+=(pow((-1),(n+1))*pow(n,1/2))/(n*(n+2));
         qDebug()<<sum<<n;
      }
      qDebug()<<"10*x<-10*b"<<sum;
  }

  P=pow((abs(1-x*exp(x-b))),1/3)+cos(b/2*x)/sin(b/2*x)*sum;
  cout <<"P="<<P;
  return 0;
}
```

У вас n должно быть не равно нулю и -2 иначе деление на ноль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня получилось, значение 1.00373, если ввожу b=-4.2,x=0.6
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может я где то ошибся и кто то укажет где. И у вас "a" не как не участвует в расчётах!

Comment: Во входном потоке задано три вещественных числа a (a > 0), b (b < 0), x (-1 < x < 1). Значения исходных данных подобраны так, что выражение имеет смысл.

Comment: В выходном - вещ. число с точностью 3 знака после запятой

Comment: Пробовал ввести значения из примера, выводит неверный ответ

Comment: @Max поже перепешу. А где в формуле"a"? Я не понимаю?

Comment: Там однотипные задания, я привёл  самое простое, чтобы разобраться, далее по нарастающей сложность. Главное - научиться решать сигму

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double a,b,x,p,sum=0,n;
  cin >> a >> b >> x;
  if ((10*x)<(-10*b))
  {
    for (double n=10*x;n<=(-10*b);n++)
    {
      sum+=(pow((-1),(n+1))*pow(n,1.0/2.0))/(n*(n+2));
    }
  }
  p=b/(2*x);
  p=cos(p)/sin(p);
  p=pow(p,3)*sum;
  p=pow((abs(1-x*exp(x-b))),1.0/3.0)+p;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << p;
  return 0;
}
```